# Does $\lim_n v_n(f) = v(f)$ for $v\in T_pM$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

Let $v \in T_pM$ for some smooth manifold,assume $v_n \in T_pM$ also.

Assume further that $\lim_n v_n = v$.

Do we have the identity that $$v_n(f) \to v(f)$$ for $f\in C^\infty(M)$

(I was tring to provd the relation  which comes from Lee's smooth manifold book page 231:

$$\left.\frac{d}{d s}\right|_{s=0} d\left(\theta_{-t_{0}}\right) \circ d\left(\theta_{-s}\right)\left(W_{\theta_{s}}\left(\theta_{t_{0}}(p)\right)\right.
=d\left(\theta_{-t_{0}}\right)\left(\left.\frac{d}{d s}\right|_{s=0} d\left(\theta_{-s}\right)\left(W_{\theta_{s}}\left(\theta_{t_{0}}(p)\right)\right)\right)$$

Where $W$ is a vector field over M.

that is same to prove(notation may differ but the idea is the same): $$\frac{d}{ds} d\theta_{t_0} (v(s)) = d\theta_{t_0}(\frac{d}{ds} v(s)) \tag{*}$$

I try to do it as follows (using definiton of differential) denote $\Delta v(s) = \frac{v(s) - v(0)}{s}$ write everything in coordinate:

$$\lim_s d\theta_{t_0} (\Delta v(s)) = \lim_{s\to 0}\sum d\theta_{t_0} (\Delta v(s))(x^i) \partial_i = \sum \lim_{s\to 0}d\theta_{t_0} (\Delta v(s))(x^i) \partial_i $$

Then
$$\sum \lim_{s\to 0}d\theta_{t_0} (\Delta v(s))(x^i) \partial_i = \sum \lim_{s\to 0}[(\Delta v(s))(x^i\circ\theta_{t_0})] \partial_i$$

If we can show $$\lim [\Delta v(s) (f)] = (\lim \Delta v(s)) f$$ then we are done

since $$ \sum \lim_{s\to 0}[(\Delta v(s))(x^i\circ\theta_{t_0})] \partial_i =  \sum d\theta_{t_0}[(\lim_{s\to 0})(\Delta v(s))](x^i) \partial_i =\sum d\theta_{t_0}(\frac{d}{ds} v(s))(x^i) \partial_i = RHS$$

Comment: I do not understand you line “assume further that $\lim v_n = n$. Are you defining it to be the inventory you wrote below? Since a priori each tangent space is just a vector space and so no notion of limit is canonically defined. Either you endow with a Riemannian metric, or you define a notion of convergence from the tangent vectors acting on smooth functions I guess.

Comment: @Son Gohan I use the same definition of limit in the Lie derivative,In the textbook,this is not specified typically,I guess it is because that no difference between them?

Comment: Well, in that case you are exploiting the structure of the Real line to take the limit, which is allowed

Comment: @Son Gohan thanks can you prove $v_n(f) \to v(f)$ ? I think if we want to use functional analysis  norm on $C^\infty(M)$ also needs to be specified?

Comment: If I were you, I would expand the question defining exactly what your book requires fort your type of convergence, so we can face the problem in your way

Comment: @Son Gohan I have tried to make the question clear,but It may seems more complicated ,the goal is to prove the formula (*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fact that every smooth manifold can be endowed with a Riemannian metric (think of this as a scalar product on each tangent space that changes smoothly along the points of the manifolds), then we can define from it a Riemannian norm and hence a Riemannian distance. As a result, a notion of limit in each tangent space pops up. With this information, all should be reduced to the familiar case but some technical changes.

Comment: Thank you for finite dimension vector space $T_pM$ all norm are equivalent so ,we can freely define it.After that easy to deduce that all $v\in T_pM$ is bounded linear functional

Comment: Indeed. Linear is also enough to assure boundedness in finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Can you help me prove that $v_n(f) \to v(f)$ I try to use $|(v-v_n) (f)| \le \|v_n-v\|\|f\|$ if norm of $f$ is finite then we are done but the problem here is $C^\infty(M)$ seems not have a norm such that for all $f$ in it $\|f\|<\infty$?